# How do I select a specific instance of an html element in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a todo list app which allows users to create todos. Right now I am building functionality using jquery which would allow users to delete tasks.

The problem is when I click the delete button on one todo the app ask me to confirm deletion on every list item. When I click "cancel delete" on one, it cancels on all of them. In other words, **I am receiving duplicative behavior on all HTML elements.**

I believe this is because all todo items are being generated from the same html.erb template, and in the template I give each element its ID so I can refer to it, but **since every ID is the same, I can't differentiate between different todo's which contain elements with the same ID.** ***How do I select a specific instance of an html element in Jquery?***

Full JS Code/HTML output:
http://jsfiddle.net/LvKED/

Rails html.erb code:

```
<%= form_for task do |form| %>
  <li>
<% if !task.completed %>
    <p> <%= task.title%></p>
    <p>&ndash; <%=task.body %></p>
     <%= form.check_box :completed, class: "completed_checkbox" %>
     <%= button_to "Delete post",{}, class:"delete_button" %>
     <%= link_to "Confirm deletion",{}, class: "confirm_links", id: "confirm_delete" %>
     <%= link_to "Cancel",{}, class: "confirm_links cancel_delete" %>
     </li>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate ID's; your original idea of using class selectors was superb -- you just need to use positioning of your buttons to target the particular elements you want to manipulate.

Comment: this part  --- id: "confirm_delete" --- you'll want to increment a counter and add that on to the id

Comment: what if you use confirm behaviour of link_to? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 2):

in the event handler you can get reference to that particular item by this line of code:

```
 var targetElement = $(event.target).closest('li');
```

Comment: Like this? 

  $("#task").on("click",".delete_button",function(event){
    var currentElement = event.target.closest('li')
    $(this).hide();

Comment: Like this -- $("#task").on("click",".delete_button",function(event){ var currentElement = event.target.closest('li').hide();

Answer (score 2):

Ishita's answer seems to be correct but I don't have the reputation to comment on his answer yet.  I think you have to wrap the "event.target" in a $() so it would be:

```
var targetElement = $(event.target).closest('li');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.. I will update my answer.. i totally forgot :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you'll be able to manipulate the buttons and links:

```
$("#task").on("click",".delete_button",function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this.form).next('.confirm_links').show()
    .next('.confirm_links').show();
    return false;
});

$("#task").on("click",".cancel_delete",function(){
    $(this).hide()
    .prev(".confirm_links").hide()
    .prev('form').find(".delete_button").show();
    return false;
});
```

Button/link Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/LvKED/5/

The demo just shows one way of targeting one element out of many that may share the same selector. Other useful jQuery features you could use are:

```
jQuery.closest()
jQuery.nextUntil()
jQuery.prevUntil()
```

Find the one that works best for you.